# Convert object of object to array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

When I get the JSON from firebase I get it in this form:

Here is a link to the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzylpg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
{nume_categorie: 'Fresh', ordine: 10, produse: {…}}
```

Which is different from my class:

```
export class CategoryDTO {
  nume_categorie!:string;
  ordine!: number;
  produse!: {[key: string] : ProductDTO}[];
}
```

Here is the product class:

```
export class ProductDTO{
  durataCoacere!: string;
  gramaj!: string
  ingrediente!: string;
  nume!: string;
  poza!: string;
  pret!: number;
  recomandari!: string;
  reducere!: number;

}
```

Because produse is an object of objects in firebase object and it is supposed to be an array of objects, as stated in the class definition.

I want to convert this object of objects into an array using the following code:

```
val.produse = Object.entries(val.produse).map((e) => ( {[e[0]]: e[1]} ))
```

But I get this conversion error:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: { [key: string]: ProductDTO; }; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: ProductDTO; }[]'.
```

When I check how it looks inside the console I get:

```
 [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id_Mixt_rodii_si_portocale_500ml: {…}}
1: {id_Portocale_500ml: {…}}
2: {id_Rodii_500ml: {…}}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Which is correct.
What am I missing with this conversion?

Comment: I haven't replicated your scenario, but, if I'm not mistaking you might need to just replace your map arrow function with this: (e) => e[1] . A stackblitz instance reproducing your scenario would be very useful.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to provide a self-contained [mre] that others can paste into a standalone IDE like [the TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpnXzw) to see what you're seeing.

Comment: More than that, you are saying that what gets printed in the console is the right thing. If we take that for granted, that would mean that you have to change the type for produse in the CategoryDTO class (which should probably be an interface since you don't have any methods, just attributes). That's what the error is basically saying thanks to the strongly typed language. So, you either update the type of produse in CategoryDTO , or you update the callback function in the map to get rid of the [ x: string] part which is not part of the produse type in CategoryDTO

Comment: @CCBet  I added a link to stackblitz where the error is reproduced, moreover i converted what firebase returns to a hard typed json file called menu.json inside the app folder. I really do not undestand the issue with my types is. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @jcalz I added a link to stackblitz where the error is reproduced

Comment: something to start with: if you look in your CategoryDTO, `produse` is AN ARRAY of objects of this type: `{[key: string] : ProductDTO}`. If you look in your menu.json, `produse` is AN OBJECT of this type {[key: string] : ProductDTO}. This mismatch has to be solved somehow. Either the data is of bad format and you need to switch from an object to an array, or the CategoryDTO is bad. Most probably, I would say the data if of bad format. You should probably receive an array of produse like this: [ { "id_Mixt_rodii_si_portocale_500ml" : { "alergeni" : "nimic" ...  } }, ... ]

Comment: You'll have to make some diffs (with some diff tool) to see what I changed in order to make the code compile. I could not say that what I did is what should be done because there are a lot of issues in your data (as mentioned in the previous comments), but this is what I managed to do in order to get the thing running and you might get an idea what was not ok: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9x55ta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmenu.json

Comment: @CCBet the thing is , this is how firebase returns the data

Comment: in this case, you need to update the CategoryDTO and some other code